# What are chess openings variations, lines which ensure delayed castling with equal probabilities on both sides; king and queen sides?

Tags: opening, statistics, castling

What are chess openings variations (lines that ensure delayed castling with equal probabilities on both sides; king side and queen side) for both white and black?

Delay to move 15-20.